# It is said that we cannot use articles with "abstract nouns" but what about "Don't tell a lie"?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, imperative-sentences

It is said that we cannot use articles with "abstract nouns". But here articles are used with them? 
I am just confused. 
How do you explain this in detail?

- Don't tell a lie.
- Speak the truth.
- I have a headache.

Comment: *It is said that we cannot use articles with "abstract nouns".* Whoever said that was wrong, because as you point out, it is *a lie*, and *the truth* is that you can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None of the nouns in your examples are what people mean when they speak of "abstract nouns".

An abstract noun designates a quality or "essence" abstracted—"taken away from"—any concrete instance. *Beauty*, for instance, is the quality we attribute to beautiful things, and *Nobility* is the quality we attribute to noble people; but we use them as abstract nouns only when we consider them as having some sort of existence apart from beautiful things and noble people.

- (It is perhaps worth mentioning that whether *beauty* and *nobility* actually exist is a very controversial philosophical question. A lot of people feel that Plato's philosophy, which treats the abstractions *beauty* and *nobility* and *good* as not merely existing but as being somehow more "real" than the things in which they are detected, is at bottom a "disease of language": an illegitimate reification of what is really nothing more than a grammatical manipulation.)

But the words we use to designate these abstract qualities can also be used to designate instances of the qualities occurring. ***The*** beauty of nature is not wholly abstract beauty but the particular beauty we find in nature. We say that a man or woman exhibits ***a certain*** nobility on a particular occasion or in a particular action.

In your examples,

- *Lie* is never an abstraction; a lie is  an untrue statement.
- *Headache* is never an abstraction; it may designate a condition suffered by a particular individual (*I have a headache*) or it may be employed as a designation for the condition considered under the aspect of etiology or treatment (*Headache may be treated with aspirin*).
- *Truth* may be an abstraction (*Beauty is Truth, Truth Beauty, that is all You know on earth and all you need to know*), but in *Tell the truth* it means not the abstraction but a statement to which truth may be attributed, a true statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is simply idiomatic, which makes it hard to understand.

We say, **"I have a headache"** and **"I have a medical condition,"** but **"I have shingles,"** and **"I have heartburn."**

We say, **"Speak [or Tell] the truth,**" but **"This is a truth worth knowing,"** or **"There is no truth in what you say."**

We say, **"Don't tell a lie,"** but **"That was untruthful,"** or **"Your lie hurt my feelings."**

These are examples of why English is so difficult to learn!

**To quote from part of @rogermue's answer** (linked in the comments below):

"A better formulation of the rule would be 'Abstract nouns are mostly used without articles, but there are cases where an article is used.' It is impossible for grammars to cover a lot of grammar points with exact rules. The handling of such 'grey' grammar zones is a matter of experience you only get by reading a lot of original texts."

Comment: See Este  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297212/does-an-abstract-noun-take-articles-before-it

Answer (score 0):

Some abstract nouns can be used in a particular sense with 
a/an, but in the singular only:

- a help: my children are a great help to me.
- a relief: it was a relief to sit down.
- a knowledge: he had a good knowledge of mathematics.
- a love: a love of music.

So, may be 'lie' come with 'a' article (according  to 'A Practical English Grammar')

Answer (score -1):

I have its answer. It is very hard to understand the rules of English Grammar, In the Sentence "Tell a lie" lie is a singular noun and it's also a rule to use "A" before singular noun for e.g. a one rupee note. And with this, there is also a rule for it , that we use article "A" only with countable nouns and we can count our lies but we can't count our truth that is the  reason to use A with Lie and The with Truth.